# Clicking outside div to close the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to close the `login-content` div when I clicked outside the div I tried event but it ain't working

I have this **html** code

```
 <nav class="login">
  <ul>
     <li id="login">
    <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
      Log in <span>▼</span>
      </a>
     <div id="login-content">
    <form>
      <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="username" type="text" name="uname"   
          placeholder="University ID" required>   
        <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" 
              placeholder="Password" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
        <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed 
          in</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>                     
  </li>
</ul>
```

this js file script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-trigger').click(function(){
$(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass('active');          

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
    else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
   }) 
 });
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with some more complete code

Comment: Do you need to remove the login-content? or just hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html code is fine , need to change js,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login-trigger').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $("#login-content").slideToggle();
    });
    $("#login-content").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup").hide();
});
```

working fiddle link here,

http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *blur* event on `#login-trigger` - for that to work note that you have to add `tabindex` attribute to the `#login-trigger` element.

```
$('#login-trigger').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

If the `login-content` is *active* this will *trigger* the click event and hide the div.

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).next('#login-content').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
    else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
  })
  
  $('#login-trigger').blur(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
      $(this).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```css
#login-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="login">
  <ul>
    <li id="login">
      <a id="login-trigger" href="#" tabindex='-1'>
      Log in <span>▼</span>
      </a>
      <div id="login-content">
        <form>
          <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input id="username" type="text" name="uname" placeholder="University ID" required>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
            <label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Keep me signed 
          in</label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like these, I would add the mouseEventHandler to the body. Here are the utility functions I keep around.

```
function _wasElemClicked(element, e: MouseEvent) {
    let { clientX: x, clientY: y } = e;
    let { height, width, top, left } = _getDimensions(element);
    if ((x > left && x < left + width) &&
        (y > top && y < top + height)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function _getDimensions(elem) {
    let { height, width, top, left } = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return { height, width, top, left }
}
```

With that I would add the following body-click handler:

```
const bodyClick = e => {
  if(!_wasElemClicked(targetElem, e) {
    // close modal/dialog/popup
    ...
    // cleanup event listener
    document.body.removeEventHandler('click', bodyClick);
  }
}
document.body.addEventHandler('click', bodyClick);
```